# How to convert object of any class to a Map in Java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC we have to use `org.springframework.ui.Model` instance to pass model to a view. It is not strongly-typed and we have to dynamically build the object like this:

```
model.addAttribute("departmentID", departmentID);
model.addAttribute("departmentName", departmentName);
model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
```

However, I came from ASP.NET MVC, where I passed strongly-typed objects to a view, and I had `ViewDepartment` class which had `departmentID`, `departmentName` and `employees` fields, and I simply passed instance to a view. Here it doesn't work, but I still need to use `ViewDepartment` class, because I occasionally send it as response to AJAX-requests.

So, to get this working in Spring MVC, I need to translate `ViewDepartment` object to instance of `org.springframework.ui.Model`, one way is to build `org.springframework.ui.Model` from `HashMap`:

```
Model.addAllAttributes(Map<String,?> attributes)
```

The question is, **how to build `Map<String,?> attributes` from instance of `ViewDepartment` class**? Creating HashMap object and manually setting each attribute from each property is not option, because it`s not DRY. I need some way to do this with any class, because I have other model classes in other controllers.

Or, may be, someone can tell another solution to this task, related to Spring MVC specifically.

Comment: *Here it doesn't work*: how doesn't it work? `model.addAttribute("viewDepartment", viewDepartment);`. Where's the problem? See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29: you can pass any object you want, including a ViewDepartment instance, to `addAttribute()`.

Comment: Either you write the code or you find a tool (there must be several, because JSON kits do this) to use reflections to extract the fields.  (But, of course, in general there should no need to Mapify your object to pass it to another class -- the class just needs to know what to do with it.)

Comment: @HotLicks: there is 0 reason to transform anything. The ViewDepartment object should be passed as attribute to the model. There's no need to pass each of its fields independently.

Comment: I will have to use "viewDepartment" in front of all my expressions in template. Which is just not right. Why? Because when I use this template on client (I use mustache) I will have the model to be wrapped into "viewDepartment" property, and when I create Backbone model out of this object, Backbone would thik that "viewDepartment" is the only real property of my object and assign events to it, instead of real properties which are wrapped.

Comment: @JBNizet - I think I said that.  About the only place where Mapifying is really needed is converting to JSON/XML.

Comment: @HotLicks: OK. I misunderstood your comment, and we agree then :-)

Comment: The template is a View for `ViewDepartment class`, not for `ViewDepartment class wrapped in anything`.

Comment: I don't know BackBone and Mustache very well, but if the goal is to transfer this object to the client and not to use it in a server-side view, why in hell aren't you sending it to the client as a JSON object? You should provide more context in your question. What are you doing with the ViewDepartment object in your view?

Comment: @JBNizet because the goal is to transfer this object to client AND to use it in a server-side view, sharing the template between the server and the client (which why I got rid of JSP in favor of Mustache in the first place).

Comment: @JBNizet instance of ViewDepartment class is rendered with the same Mustache template on a server and on a client. On a server with a first GET request to application, and on a client with following requests from browser, which are all-AJAX.

Comment: @JBNizet finally I just will not be able to use this template (with "viewDepartment-prefix") on a client, because on a client this model will not be wrapped (it has to be not wrapped, because it wouldn't act right as BackBone model otherwise). In ASP.NET MVC everything worked fine, so in Spring MVC there also should be a way to pass normal strongly-typed object to a view, without wrapping anything

Comment: If I were you, I would tag my question with mustache and Backbone, and I would show the code of the server-side view and the code of the client-side view, and explain what I'm trying to achieve, by editing my question. It seems to be a mustache problem or an architecture problem more than a Java or Spring MVC problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I take the liberty to disagree. It is not Java problem, it's Spring MVC problem, that I can't pass strongly-typed object as a model. It is full and complete representation of my entity, which I pass to it's view, which determine how this particular entity looks in HTML. Why do I have to wrap it in something and modify template? If I wrap my model (which is wrong and there is no reason why this should be done), this would also cause changes in all other application layers. There is nothing wrong with Backbone and Mustache. I marked with "Java" because workaround to this leads to Java.

Comment: I didn't say something was wrong. I said that, given that we have no clue about what you're doing, because you didn't post any code, it's hard for us (to me at least), to understand what the actual problem is, and what could the best solution be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use reflection to get a map of all fields and their values. Be aware, that this gets complicated, if you have nested structures, but with the given example it should work,

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap( Object object ) throws Exception
{
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for ( Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields() )
    {
        field.setAccessible( true );
        map.put( field.getName(), field.get( object ) );
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: No problem with nested objects, because in my case all I need is go thru first-level properties and get their values. Nested values can remain being objects, no need them to be maps. Thank you!